# Is it possible to use a XSLT to check if a string is Null/ Empty

Tags: xslt, sharepoint, null, sharepoint-workflow

I'm doing a workflow for a SharePoint site that is taking data from another SharePoint sites list and then putting it into the new site, I have this bit working fine but I have a issue where it seems to be updating both lists due to one of the logic operations thinking that a value is not null. My question is would it be possible to use an XSLT to set a sort of Boolean that will return True when a string == Null? and if so could you give me some pointers on how to get started with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
not ($yourString)
```

will return True if the string is empty, False otherwise. Not sure what "null" means in this context

Comment: Thanks, ill give it a try now but it looks like this should work.